# How can I restore a transmogrified item's original appearance?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found some lvl 70 set shoulders today. By mistake (I realise now) I changed the look of them, how do I get the original look back (if possible)?

[image: Screenshot of transmogrify screen for shoulders]

Answer (score 8):

By hovering over all the possible looks, you will eventually see *Original* on one of them. That is the one you should use to restore a transmogrified item look back to normal.

[image: Cropped screenshot of transmogrify widget for shoulders]

**EDIT**

You only get *Legendary* skins for *Transmogrification* if you **identified** these items yourself. So if you don't see the original appearance of that item, I would assume that you are not the one who identified it. In this case the answer would be:

**It's not possible to change the look back to normal unless you find the same unidentified item and identify it yourself**

Comment: Yeah, unfortunatly it is not that easy - I've added a picture.

Comment: The transmogrified item only looks different on the character, in the inventory, its look never changes. Match the pictures. Unless you are saying that particular item choice does no appear in the whole list which is not in your picture

Comment: It does not appear on the list. I can't change it back to the original look.

Comment: As Novarg said in his edit, if the item is legendary (or a set piece) and you either did not identify it yourself, or it is a legacy item (e.g. you found it BEFORE the 2.0 patch), then the appearance will remain locked and inaccessible.  You'll have to find another item with the same appearance to be able to restore the original appearance.  Otherwise you're **SOL**.

Comment: I found it today, and I was the one to identify it...

Comment: @Troels then you seem to have encountered a bug and should open a ticket about it and/or post in the official forum's help & support section.

Answer (score 0):

There are some set and legendary looks that are not transmogrifable, ie. you cannot transmogrify item to have its look.

Unfortunately it means that you cannot restore the look of such item if you have it transmogrified.

---

Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12372857277?page=2#22

> It's not technically a bug, but there are some items (like class-specific set items) that don't exist as Transmogrify options. Some of those items can't be Transmogrified back into their original state once they've been altered, either. We're aware that this is causing issues for some players, and we'll be looking at solutions. We'll give everyone an update when we're able to, and thanks for letting us know!